# Spring Boot: Datasource properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a confusion regarding datasource autoconfiguration in Spring-boot. From what I have read, we have to specify the datasource properties in the form `spring.datasource.*`. But my application code works fine if I supply property name in the form `SPRING_DATASOURCE_*`. Is there any reason that I am missing, due to which it works? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You've come across a feature of spring boot called ***Relaxed Binding***.

It allows using some "relaxed" rules for binding to ConfigurationProperties. So essentially both ways of definition have the same effect in your application.

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) you can find a link to the relevant chapter in the official documentation

Comment: Both answers actually explain my confusion, but I can accept only one.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot has so-called Relaxed Binding
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding which allows you to define configuration in different ways:

- acme.my-project.person.first-name
  acme.myProject.person.firstName
- acme.myProject.person.firstName
- acme.my_project.person.first_name
- ACME_MYPROJECT_PERSON_FIRSTNAME

The latter is often used when passed via environment variables.